# Does Azure SQL Server supports Query Notifications?

Tags: azure

We wanted to know whether QueryNotifications is supported in Azure SQL Server.

Here is the reference url of QueryNotifications - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/query-notifications-in-sql-server

however nowhere it is mentioned whether it is supported with Azure SQL or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query notification uses service broker.

Service broker is supported in Azure SQL managed instances, with some limitations. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-ver15

So looks like it is supported by Azure SQL managed instances but not by Azure SQL.

The feature has been requested: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/5495973-allow-using-query-notifications-with-azure-sql-dat